# phpmyadmin, when inserting a record using the form tools provided it comes up with an error

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

When inserting a record using the tools in phpmyadmin, it puts in a `''` when it should either not put anything or a `null` or a `0`. phpmyadmin that generates the sql code has errors on it.

The error (more suitably a Warning) is:

1 row inserted.
Inserted row id: 17
Warning: #1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'userNo' at row 1

The sql generated by phpmyadmin is:

```
INSERT INTO plenty_of_singles.user (
    userNo ,
    username ,
    password ,
    email ,
    gender ,
    age ,
    country ,
    area ,
    city ,
    relocate ,
    height ,
    weight ,
    overview
)
VALUES (
'', 'girl101', MD5( 'weebling' ) , 'girl101@hotmail.com', 'female', '18', 'UK', 'England', 'Manchester', 'yes', '5''8"', '50 kg', 'Genuine girl who would like to find the right person.'
);
```

It would be nice to know a solution and if anyone else has had or has this problem.

mysql version 5.0.10    .

sql code for table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (  
`userNo` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
`username` varchar(16) NOT NULL COMMENT 'username, alphanumeric 16 characters long.',  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'password alphanumeric 16 characters long , but when encrypted using MD5 it becomes a hexidecimal number 32 digits long',  
`email` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'email is an alphanumeric 40 characters long',  `gender` varchar(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'gender is alphanumeric and will always be male or female',  
`age` int(3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'age will be an integer 3 digits long',  
`country` varchar(35) NOT NULL COMMENT 'country is alphabetic 35 characters long',  
`area` varchar(35) NOT NULL COMMENT 'area is alphabetic 35 characters long',  
`city` varchar(35) NOT NULL COMMENT 'city is alphabetic 35 characters long',  
`relocate` varchar(3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'relocate is a alphabetic 3 characters long. possible values are yes or no',  
`height` varchar(15) NOT NULL COMMENT 'height is alphanumeric and 15 chracters long.',  `weight` varchar(15) NOT NULL COMMENT 'wieight is alphanumeric and 15 chracters long.',  `overview` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`userNo`),  
UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: What MySQL version is running on the server? For an auto_increment column, an empty string will be taken the same way `NULL` would.  Wait, _is that an auto_increment column_?  If not, the empty string '' should cast to integer 0.

Comment: You'd better post the table structure.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE plenty_of_singles`

Comment: Seems like 5.0.10 won't accept `''` for an auto increment field. Since I am not too familiar with phpmyadmin I don't know what a workaround would be (except to hand-type the SQL, which is what I always do anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not give value to userNo field beacuase its auto increment field use this query

```
          INSERT INTO plenty_of_singles.user (

username ,
password ,
email ,
gender ,
age ,
country ,
area ,
city ,
relocate ,
height ,
weight ,
overview
)
VALUES (
  'girl101', MD5( 'weebling' ) , 'girl101@hotmail.com', 'female', '18', 'UK','England', 'Manchester', 'yes', '5''8"', '50 kg', 'Genuine girl who would like to find the right person.'
  );
```